# How to fix database error in which exists function is used?

Tags: php

```
$this->db->select('u.name, u.file', false);
$this->db->from('users_domains as u');
$this->db->where("EXISTS('domain as d', 'd.id = u.domain_id')");
$query = $this->db->get();
```

> Error Number: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''domain as d', 'd.id = u.domain_id')' at line 3 SELECT u.name, u.file FROM users_domains as u WHERE EXISTS('domain as d', 'd.id = u.domain_id') Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/codeminiproject/system/database/DB_driver.php Line Number: 691

Comment: This is the error which it is showing every time.

Comment: __Never__ paste codes in comment. [Edit] question instead.

Comment: instead of this `$this->db->where("EXISTS('domain as d', 'd.id = u.domain_id')");` write `$this->db->join('domain as d', 'd.id = u.domain_id','inner');`

Comment: Rahul Meshram It's working but showing blank screen.Is there any problem in following code chunk: $query = $this->db->get();

Comment: Sorry u_mulder it's my first on stackoverflow 'Ask Question'.

Comment: What is `$this->db`? Do you use any framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`where` need to be `join`

```
$this->db->join('domain as d', 'd.id = u.domain_id','inner');
$query = $this->db->get();
$result =  $query->result();
```

Now use this `$result` wherever you want into HTML

If this code is inside any function, and you want to return data through that function, then do:

```
return $query->result(); // instead of $result =  $query->result();
```